# Is it possible to display rtsp stream in a Vue app using GStreamer? Using Node.js and Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, gstreamer, rtsp

I have an IP camera that streams continuously via RTSP and I'd like to display that stream in a DOM element in my Vue.js app. I can access the stream using a GStreamer pipeline and sink it either locally or on a tcp server but I can't get it to display in my Vue.js app. Has anybody tried this?

Comment: Whats your problem? "but I can't get it to display in my Vue.js app" is not a clear error message/problem...

Comment: Is not necessarily a detailed technical problem involving an error code or message. I'm just looking for a reliable strategy to do it . In case anyone has done it before.
But to be more specific with respect to what I have tried I can say the following. I created a GStreamer pipeline to send the frames from the rtsp server to an http server and then accessing 'localhost:port' to view the livestream which works alright when I run it as a standalone project. However when I try it from the vue app I get the following message. (Posted in the following comment)

Comment: 'The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. 127.0.0.1:85'